# Is it possible to make subfolders in the "Show View" menu?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Let's say I have some view called "My View".
I know I can create a category, "My Category", and place my view inside it.
I'd like to create a subfolder/category inside "My Category" called "Sub Folder" and place my view inside it.
Then the view would be found through the "Show View" popup as follows:

My Category -> Sub Folder -> My View

I know you can do this with exports/imports, but it doesn't seem like you can with views.

Here is a sample plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            name="My Category"
            id="My_Category">
      </category>
      <category
            id="My_Sub_Folder"
            name="Sub Folder"
            parentCategory="My_Category">
      </category>
      <view
            name="My View"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            category="My_Sub_Folder"
            class="sample_plugin.views.SampleView"
            id="sample_plugin.views.SampleView">
      </view>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

However, when I use the plugin.xml above, the view category does not show up and the view is found in the "Other" category. If I change the view category back to "My_Category", the view shows up in the parent category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(revised answer)

You can set up a parent category hierarchy, but the Show View menu will not respect this.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=92894

So the answer is effectively no.

Here is the documentation on setting up the useless parent category:

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_views.html

Comment: Like I've said, I've had success using the parent category for imports and exports, but not views. I tried it again, and the views either end up in the parent category or in the "Other" folder.
Also, to clarify, I set the view's category to [parent category]/[sub category]

Comment: That's what you are doing wrong. You have to define a parent category, say p, and then a child category, say c, setting the parentCategory attribute in the child category to p. Then in your category for the view, say only 'c', not 'p/c'.

Comment: I previously tried what you described, but tried it again to give you benefit of the doubt. I'll have to do some more digging to figure out why I'm not able to do this. 
I have no problem making subfolders in the import or export menus, it just doesn't want to work for views.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've made view subfolders before?

Comment: Can you revised your original post to show the parts of your plugin.xml that create and use the categories?

Comment: Finally revised original question with sample plugin.xml.

Comment: Well I looked into it more and revised my answer. Sorry for misleading you.

Answer (score 0):

it could be that your using package explorer.  Switch to Navigator (window-->show view ---> other -------> Navigator)

now you can see the project as folders instead of packages.

Comment: We're talking about the menu from which you can select a view.
Select **Window** --> **Show View** --> **Other...**

The window that pops up is what we're talking about.